# In Openlayers, Why would my label disappear after i finished drawing a circle?

Tags: openlayers

I have a circle drawing mode.  When you draw a circle in this mode, as  you are dragging the circle to the right size i have a label that displays the radius of that circle.  This label disappears right after I finish drawing the circle.  How do i get this circle to stay and display after it is complete?  I am not sure why the label is going away.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by using persist: true.

```
var polyOptions = {sides: 40, persist: true, style: style};
```